# Disable annoying textbox tooltips in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

Everytime I move my cursor onto an input field (like a textbox), I get this annoying pop-up displaying information I'm never going to need. This happens on all websites. I'm using the latest version of Microsoft Edge (98.0.1108.50 (Official build) (64-bit)). Does anyone know how to disable this menace?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you (or any extension you installed) turned on the `Show Autofill predictions` flag under `edge://flags`?

Comment: @derpirscher thanks a lot! I just went and disabled that, and it seems to have solved the problem. No idea which extension toggled that flag though.